# Return char * value

Tags: c, function, pointers, char, return-value

I have a problem in my code with the return value. In this part, the return value is printed well:

```
char *getUserName(){

char username[50];
DWORD username_len = 50;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
char *returnValue=username;
printf("user: %s\n\n",returnValue);
return returnValue;}


char *getSystemName(){

TCHAR szComputerName[256];
DWORD cchComputerName = 256;
GetComputerName(szComputerName, &cchComputerName);
char *returnValue=szComputerName;
printf("system: %s",returnValue);
return returnValue;}
```

but, when I use like return value in main, it returns crazy things (sometimes it returns well system name):

```
int main(){
char *userName = getUserName();
char *systemName = getSystemName();

printf("user: %s \n\n",userName);
printf("system: %s",systemName);
return 0;}
```

Comment: The string `username` is allocated on the stack, not on the heap, so when the function is returned its value *may* be overwritten. You must either allocated it dynamically on the heap (via `malloc`) or allocate it in the caller and pass a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you returned a pointer to local variable in `getUserName()` which led to undefined behavior:

```
char *returnValue=username;
...
return returnValue;
```

There are two ways to fix that:

1) Change prototype of `char *getUserName()` to `void getUserName(char username[])

You will need to provide a buffer `username` before calling `getUserName`

2) Keep prototype `char *getUserName()`, but you will need to `malloc` `username` inside that function. Also you must manually `free` that `username` in `main`

Comment: Same mistake in `char *getSystemName()`

Comment: @WeatherVane yes exactly the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with using malloc function. Thanks a lot. Here is the new code:

```
char *getUserName(){
char username[50];
DWORD username_len = 50;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);

char *returnValue=(char *)malloc(strlen(username)+1);
strcpy(returnValue,username);

return returnValue;}
```

And the same for the other function